how to update each object in a json array using jq
I have an array of objects that looks like this:
[
    {"host": "1.exampl.com", "path": "/dir1/file.html"},
    {"host": "2.exampl.com", "path": "/dir2/file.html"},
    {"host": "3.exampl.com", "path": "/dir3/file.html"}
]


and I want to add a new key in each of those objects, which will create the URL using the host and path, so I would look like this:
[
    {"host": "1.exampl.com", "path": "/dir1/file.html", "url": "http://1.example.com/dir1/file.html"},
    {"host": "2.exampl.com", "path": "/dir2/file.html", "url": "http://2.example.com/dir2/file.html"},
    {"host": "3.exampl.com", "path": "/dir3/file.html", "url": "http://3.example.com/dir3/file.html"}
]

how can I do that using jq.
I tried doing ".[] |= . { . + {\"url\": \"http://\" + .host + .path } }"
but this didn't work and it returned this error:
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:

Both, your input and your desired output, are not valid JSON. The inner items need to be separated by commas, and the outer container should be an array using brackets: [{…}, {…}, {…}]

You can get the desired results using $.each function, here is an example of code

var newResources = [];
$.each(resources, function(index, item) {
    var fullUrl = 'http://' + item.host + item.path;
    var newItem = $.extend({}, item, {url: fullUrl}); // Cloning item and adding new key
    newResources.push(newItem);
});
console.log(newResources);

your solution uses js while I want it using jq.

currently, you should get a different error message.

you can try this
echo '[
    {"host": "1.exampl.com", "path": "/dir1/file.html"},
    {"host": "2.exampl.com", "path": "/dir2/file.html"},
    {"host": "3.exampl.com", "path": "/dir3/file.html"}
]' | jq '.[] |= . + {"url": ("http://" + .host + .path)}'


In your filter, the part . { . + { is not valid in jq.
Try one of the following filters:
.[] |= (.url = "http://" + .host + .path)

map(.url = "http://" + .host + .path)

.[] |= (.url = "http://\(.host)\(.path)")

map(.url = "http://\(.host)\(.path)")

These filters can be wrapped as-is into single quotes: jq '…'. If you prefer double quotes, you need to escape certain characters (like you did with \").
